# Unable to call controller function from child view in angularjs using ui router

Tags: angularjs

Config of the **module** is

```
home.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
```

** Here i have done loading of two child views(startPracticeCase.html,steps.html) in main view(partial-startPracticeCase.html) **

```
.state('startPracticeCase', {
      url: '/startPracticeCase',
      views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'templates/partial-startPracticeCase.html'},
        'startPracticeContent@startPracticeCase': { templateUrl: 'templates/startPracticeContent.html' },
        'steps@startPracticeCase': { 
            templateUrl: 'templates/steps.html'            
            }
      }
    })

   ** here i am changing first child view with another one whenever user click on different steps available on steps.html **

  .state('startPracticeCase.casePatientHistory', {
      url: '/casePatientHistory',
      views: { 
         '': { templateUrl: 'templates/partial-startPracticeCase.html',controller: 'subjectiveQuestions' },       
        'startPracticeContent@startPracticeCase': 
            { 
                templateUrl: 'templates/casePatientHistory.html'  ,
                controller: 'serverData'
            },  
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

 }]);
```

**Controller:**

```
home.controller('serverData',function ($state,$scope,$location,DataLoadingService){ 
    $scope.subjectiveQuestions = function (ref) {
        console.log(this.id);
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        DataLoadingService.SubjectiveQuestions(function(response) {         
            if(response) { 
                $scope.questions=response;  
                console.log("$scope.questions :: "+response);
                //$state.go('startPracticeCase.casePatientHistory');
            }else { 
                //$scope.error = response.message;
                $scope.error = 'error';             
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

** I am trying to call subjectiveQuestions function on click of steps available on steps.html**

I wrote following things in anchor tag but the controller method/fun is not called .

```
< ui-sref="startPracticeCase.casePatientHistory" ng-click="subjectiveQuestions ()" > Subjective Interview</>
```

One more thing the index.hml page of my app have one ui-view in which i am loading partial-startPracticeCase.html this page also have two ui-view

Comment: Do you want to change the view and controller function call at the same time ?

Comment: yes i want the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Call the controller function first then use [$state.go(your_state)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) like

In `html`

```
<a href ng-click="subjectiveQuestions()">Subjective Interview</a>
```

In `controller`

```
$scope.subjectiveQuestions = function () {
    //other code
    $state.go('state_name'); //set your state where you want to go
};
```

Comment: i did the same as you suggest but still unable to call  controller function

Comment: Is not the anchor `<a href ..` inside of `casePatientHistory.html` ?